# where put images files in big multimodules web app

Tags: html, image, jsp, web-applications, static-content

I have big WEB application (jsp). What is the best way to put images files? Where to put images files in multi modules web application?

I have many images so I would like to have easy, separate access to modify them. The best way will be some separate project which I can redeploy without stop my main application part. Is this solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is completely acceptable. You can create an "assets" project, and have `images/module1/`, `images/module2/` folders, etc.

Just, in your main application, you will need to configure the path to the assets application. It can even reside on a different host. For example  `http://assets.yoursite.com`. And then in your main application you'll have:

```
<img src="${assetServer}/images/module1/logo.png" />
```

(the assetServer request attribute may be put there and configured in multiple ways, depending on the setup and your preferences. One example is - configure as context-param in web.xml, and put in the request by a filter)

Comment: sounds good but what with .CSS file (body {background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');} I can't use ${assetServer}?

Comment: @smas - it is usually the case that the CSS are part of the assets project. If you are not willing to do so, you an process your .css files through the JSP servlet, thus enabling `${..}`

Comment: thanks for you answers (not only here) - I collect your answers and I won't modify my jsp but only create filter which take all request to /images into NEW_SERVER/images. It will be configurable from web.xml (e.g changing path to new server) and small work is necessary to do this job (without big refactoring, only creating new filter)

Comment: aha. yes, at some point I realized I'm answering the same person :)